# Force ESX(i) to check the consistency of your bootbank/boot.cfg

Tags: vmware-esxi

I recall once copying a bad tgz file to my bootbank and specifying to load it in `boot.cfg`. Needless to say this was bad - Purple Screen of Death, no boot, bad - and I should have been more careful. But is there a way to check the consistency of your files in `boot.cfg`, as in simulating what would happen at that point, so that you know *before* hand whether there is a corrupt `tgz` file or invalid `boot.cfg` option?

Comment: Problem with your media? I've never seen this.

Comment: @ewwhite It failed because it didn't like `ghettoVCB.tgz` specifically. It would not boot. After booting into with a live CD, removing the inclusion in `boot.cfg` and deleting the `ghettoVCB.tgz` file, it could boot.

Comment: Sounds pretty unsupported...

Comment: @ewwhite, it's absolutely unsupported, but I was just wondering if there is a consistency checking program in ESXi as it must do something like this when it is booting to figure out it cannot boot...

Comment: Erm have you tried something simple like installing ESXi in a VM, then simply trying your adding your tgz on a VM before adding it on production?

Comment: No, but that certainly sounds worthwhile!